# Can I prevent window.onbeforeunload when saving file uploaded to asp:fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I'm setting window.onbeforeunload on aspx page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
              window.onbeforeunload = ShowMessage;

              function ShowMessage()
      {   
          alert("Do you want to close?")
      }
</script>
```

I'm referring a user controls to my aspx page. In my Ascx control, i had one fileupload and asp button.

Once i uploaded a file and clicked on button to save it, before it hitting code behind file, for some reason javascript function ShowMessage() is popping up. 
Is there any way that I can restrict this from happening. I don't need this message to pop-up when i uploaded file and clicked on Button to save. Please suggest me how to resolve

Ascx.code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsave" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <div id="div1" runat="server" >
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="dcupload" runat="server"  />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save"  CausesValidation="false" />
                </div>
            </p>
            <asp:Panel ID="UIPanelEnabled" runat="server">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvresults" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function `DisableMessage` that resets the `onbeforeunload` event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = ShowMessage;

    function DisableMessage() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }

    function ShowMessage() {
        return "Do you want to close?";
    }
</script>
```

And call that function in the `OnClientClick` event of the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" OnClientClick="DisableMessage();" ... />
```

By the way, simply returning a string in `ShowMessage` (as shown above) allows the `onbeforeunload` event handler to work in all browsers, which is not the case if you call `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is that in any link on the page is firing the onbeforeunload when clicked unless it's a link to the same page.

Adding a "return false" to the onclick event of each link (most of the elements in the  control are links that fire off javascript but don't go anywhere).  Here is the code I put on my page .

```
$('#id').click(function (e) {
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change javascript to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = ShowMessage;

 function ShowMessage()
 {   if(this.id.indexOf("btnsave") == -1)
         alert("Do you want to close?")
 }
 </script>
```

This will check if something with id that contains "btnsave" is calling that function.